# A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) in Okhttp

Tags: android, android-studio, okhttp

I am using **volley** in android and while requesting from url, most of time I am getting  fatal signal error  in android studio.

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageRequest imageRequest =new com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageRequest(Constants.SERVERURL + id + "/" + imageFileName, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Bitmap loadedImage) {
                progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(1);
                File file = new File(PATH+"/"+id+"/"+imageFileName);
                if(!file.exists()){                        saveBitmap(loadedImage,file,Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP);
                }


            }
        }, 0, 0, null, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(imageRequest);
```

Here is my Stack trace:

```
[OkHttp] sendRequest<<
I/System.out: Wrong owner. Perhaps a late disconnect
I/Choreographer: Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too 
much work on its main thread.
I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
I/System.out: Wrong owner. Perhaps a late disconnect
I/Choreographer: Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too 
much work on its main thread.
I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
[OkHttp] sendRequest<<
I/System.out: Wrong owner. Perhaps a late disconnect
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x6d080000 in tid 
22280 (p.tamilstickers)
Application terminated.
```

Comment: So you use Volley with the OkHttp stack? Also, why do you think the SIGSEGV and the network request are related?

Comment: It is related to signal so I think SIGSEGV is okhttp related issue. After spending sometimes now I think it is because of heavy load (saving bitmap). @Henry